# How to apply list filters on a dropdown lists(Duplicated , Asking for further info)

Tags: jquery

I have asked ["How to apply list filters on a dropdown lists"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762263/how-to-apply-list-filters-on-a-dropdown-lists) question and got answers. But the solution is not working in Internet explorer. Please someone debug this code.
Here is the link

http://jsfiddle.net/ymSbu/

Comment: What's the problem? Could you provide the error message? What have you done to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: I can not see any result. Actually the stubs in the second dropdown have to be displayed based on the option selected in first dropdown.But it is working fine in mozilla. But not working in IE.

Comment: Actually there is a problem in IE. Try to read this - http://work.arounds.org/issue/96/option-elements-do-not-hide-in-IE/ . The idea is using "wrap('<span>')" method in order to hide option and "unwrap('<span>')" to show option (but you should unwrap only if you already wrapped option before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a gross simplification of what you're trying to do, it assumes that the options in the two select lists will always be the same, and you want to set the second dropdown's option to be the select value of the first (except when "please select" is chosen, and then it should be all the options).  Assuming this is the case, then:

```
$('#a').live('change',function()
{
  var firstSelect = $(this),
      otherSelect = $('#b'),
      selectedItem = $(this).children(':selected'),
      itemsToClone = selectedItem.val() ? selectedItem : firstSelect.children(':gt(0)');

  otherSelect
    .children(':gt(0)')
      .remove()
    .end()
    .append(itemsToClone.clone());
});
```

It has the added overhead of DOM manipulation, but the advantage of working in all browsers.

Example in jsbin: http://jsbin.com/anihec/3

Answer (score 0):

This should sort it out for you

```
$(function () {


        $('#a').live('change', function () {
            selectedElement = $(this).find("option:selected");
            if (selectedElement) {
                $('#b').empty().append("<option value='0'>Select answer</option>" + selectedElement.get(0).outerHTML).val(0);
            }
        });

    });
```

html:

```
    <table>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <select class="dropdown" id="a">
  <option value="">Select answer</option>
  <option value="1" >Yes</option>
  <option value="2">No</option>
  <option value="3">N.A.</option>
  </select>
  </td>
  <td>
  <select class="dropdown" id="b">
    <option value='0'>Select answer</option>
  </select>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```